# how i can show all data from get api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have trouble displaying data, all data is received correctly from Get method, but I can not handle it to show values.

in the `getDataLadder` successfully received data in `response.body` and i can see result with `print('Response Body : ${response.body}');`

with this section i store data in `stringResponse` value , but i can't show json data in this section:

```
  Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.white),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  stringResponse.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Column(
                children: List.generate(nardeban_data.length, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            image: new AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 90,
                              // width: (size.width - 20) * 0.68,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(width: 20), // give it width
                                  Container(
                                      width: 40,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                          child: Text("14",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Colors.white)))),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          nardeban_data[index]['name'],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: (size.width - 120) * 0.32,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 10,
                                          bottom: 4,
                                          left: 10,
                                          top: 4),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 25,
                                            height: 25,
                                            child: TextField(
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              keyboardType:
                                                  TextInputType.number,
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                hintText: '4%',
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  bottom: 8,
                                                  top: 3,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Icon(
                                  //   Icons.notifications,
                                  //   size: 22,
                                  //   color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
                                  // )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              );
            })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is my json style when i get from api:

```
{
    "pellekan": [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "form": null,
            "to": "1000000",
            "percent": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "form": "1000000",
            "to": 1100000,
            "percent": 2.89
        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "form": "1000000",
            "to": 1200000,
            "percent": 4.79
        },
    ]
}
```

also this is my class and i difine `stringResponse` value out of that

```
 var stringResponse = [];

class ResultLadder extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);

  const ResultLadder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResultLadderState createState() => _ResultLadderState();
}

Future<String> getToken() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('login')!;
}

class _ResultLadderState extends State<ResultLadder> {
  String token = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    // getInfo();
    getDataLadder();
    super.initState();
  }
```

generally, for example how i can show `name` in json data instead of `"14"` , in this below:code:

```
child: Text("14",
     style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 13.0,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     color: Colors.white))
```

this is `getDataLadder` Code :

```
  Future getDataLadder() async {
    print('bye');
    String token = await getToken();
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://mylocalapiurl.com/backend/api/v1/pellekan/main/active'),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });
    print('Token : ${token}');
    print('Response Body : ${response.body}');
        
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        stringResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
    
  }
```

nardeban ladder is one file in data folder and i add this values for show data demo (this is working):

````
const List nardeban_data = [
  {
    "img":
        "https://images.unsplash.com/image.jpg",
    "name": "mark wiliams",
    "takhfif": "description item"
  },
  {
    "img":
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610859923380-c8e5a13165d1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "name": "joe mark",
    "takhfif": "description item"
  },
];```
````

Comment: Can you show the code inside the **getDataLadder()** method? Also show a bit of how you are populating the property called ** nardeban_data**.

Comment: @RomanJaquez i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now use your **stringResponse** since it has already been decoded into JSON, I'd create a small PODO (Plain Ol' Dart Object) to map my JSON to the data you're receiving, as in:

```dart
class NardebanData {
   String? name;
   String? form;
   String? to;
   double? percent;
  
   NardebanData({ this.name, this.form, this.to, this.percent });
 
   factory NardebanData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
     return NardebanData(
        name: json['name'],
        form: json['form'], 
        to: json['to'],
        percent: json['percent']
     );
   }
}
```

Inside your **setState()** call, then map it as such:

```dart
setState(() {
 
 stringResponse = json.decode(response.body);

 nardeban_data = (stringResponse['pellekan'] as List<dynamic>).map((d) => NardebanData.fromJson(d)).toList();
});
```

So make your **nardeban_data** not a **const** anymore, but a List of **NardebanData** objects:

```dart
List<NardebanData> narbeban_data = [];
```

And when you consume it (inside of your List.generate) you could fetch the current object in the iteration, as in:

```dart
children: List.generate(nardeban_data.length, (index) {
   // fetch the item in the collection by the index provided
   NardebanData dataItem = nardeban_data[index];

   // ALL YOUR WIDGET STRUCTURE HERE
   // LIKE YOUR TEXT WIDGETS AS IN:
   Text(
     dataItem.name!, // pull the data out of the dataItem using the provided properties
     style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 14,
       color: Colors.black54,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
}
```

Also make sure your JSON data coming from your API is consistent as far as the type of data in each field, otherwise the decoding will fail (i.e. make sure that **name**, **form**, **to** are Strings, and percent is a **double**).

See if that works for you.

Comment: thank for your answer , but i have a error in setState , in this line ```nardeban_data = stringResponse['pellekan'].map((d) => NardebanData.fromJson(d))```give me a error ```nardeban_data = stringResponse['pellekan'].map((d) => NardebanData.fromJson(d))``` and ```Error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'NardebanData'.``` also ```Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.```

Comment: You could try to cast the stringResponse into a List<dynamic>., as in: **(stringResponse[‘pellekan’] as List<dynamic>).map**; this is based on the sample json output you put above that there is a property called pellekan that contains the array of objects

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, can you put this in the code above?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the code; here's also a DartPad Gist so you can see how it works in real time. Just hit "Run" and see the outcome on how I'm parsing your data.

https://dartpad.dev/?c0eaeb623b66d2d7e33e9ec9920838c3

Comment: thank you Roman , i test that but we have a issue in ```['pellekan']``` | tell me this after command flutter run : ```Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
        nardeban_data = (stringResponse['pellekan'] as List<dynamic>).map((d) => NardebanData.fromJson(d)).toList();```

Comment: by the way, i define ```stringResponse``` below ```List<NardebanData> narbeban_data = [];``` like this , ```List<NardebanData> stringResponse = [];``` , it's true?

Comment: Yes that’s good - but check again the values that are coming from your API - you’re getting that error above because one of the properties is not the correct type - make sure they map correctly.

Comment: mr Roman i set these class like this : ```String? name;
   String? form;
   int? to;
   double? percent```

and my last api result is like this: ```{
    "pellekan": [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "form": null,
            "to": "1000000",
            "percent": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "lastname",
            "form": "1000000",
            "to": 1100000,
            "percent": 2.899999999999954465439991
        },
        ``` but still have same error: ```unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'```    :((((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242283/discussion-between-roman-jaquez-and-sara).